# How to add font awesome icons?

Tags: font-awesome

Font Awesome icon is not loading

this is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eb5f64bb0d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div m-5>
        <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
        <p>google</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error

```
eb5f64bb0d.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

what is wrong in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are trying to load returns a status 403. Do you have access to this resource and are you loading the literal value `randomstring.js` or do you have a value provided by FontAwesome like `6e7c0a9cd2`?

kit.fontawesome.com sends you it should a value. I just signed up with an account replaced the randomstring.js with the random string they gave me for the file name in your code sample and it worked.

See [sandbox here with your js file and sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-mendel-zg2t6)

Comment: eb5f64bb0d.js this is my random string, and I am using it correctly. It's still not working

Comment: Looks like it is working. See `index.html` in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-mendel-zg2t6.